# Adding More Materials for Photoshop 3D

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, texture, cs6

I have been using the 3d features in Photoshop CS6 Extended and I love all of the materials that are included and that you can download from Adobe's website. However, I have been trying to find some additional materials and I'm wondering if anyone has created some, or if someone out there knows where I could find some. I have searched online for them but so far no cigar. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@daveMac:  I'm glad you like them.  I made the 36 materials, as well as the 100+ at Photoshop.com for Adobe's CS 5 release. During the CS 6 build was was tasked with redesigning the UX (User eXperience) and we did not get time to make or release new materials.  We may in the future, so watch [Photoshop.com's 3D content page](http://www.photoshop.com/products/photoshop/3d) for an update, is all I can say...

The materials that we shipped with are nice examples of simple materials (not very many texture maps) but many of the additional 100+ materials that you can download at Photoshop.com are even more interesting once you start to look at them.  Basically I created the texture maps as smart objects, so if you open them you'll see that there are several layers; fill, adjustment, smart filter/smart objects, etc...  The best part is, they are all fully editable—I made them with a non-destructive thought in mind. (^_^)

Here is a blog article I wrote as an [introduction to materials in Photoshop](http://blog.ablepear.com/2010/06/photoshop-cs5-introduction-to-materials.html)—created in Photoshop CS 5 Extended.  (You'll see that I was going to write more, articles, but I have not had the chance.)

So, open those materials, and look inside.  Almost all Smart Filters/Smart Object you can just double click and inspect/edit the Filter Gallery effects, hit okay, and switch back to your 3D Scene and it will update—render and see what you made.  Check out the Fabric, Tiles, Stone and Wood, as I believe those will provide you with the best insight on how to start easily creating your own.

Lastly, in [Photoshop Dimensions](http://www.photoshopdimensions.com), each issue talks about Materials and deconstructs them, and the magazine will continue to do article(s) on materials in each issue—I know, as I'm the editor-in-chief... and I love materials.  The first issue is free and provides an overview of all that is new in Photoshop CS 6 Extended's 3D user experience.  There's an overview of the Material's properties, but I did not dive into texture maps in issue 1; Issue 2 started the material studies but is not free.

I hope this helps and if I can remember, I'll come back here and post when new materials go up on Photohop.com.  Also, let us know if you make some funky new materials.  I always love to see what we, the community, can create.  Cheers!